# Autocomplete not working for dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

I am having a bit of trouble trying to add a autocomplete field to my dynamically created content. Previously it worked fine as the textbox was generated in HTML, but I cannot figure how to make it work with dynamically generated content (even trough I am using static textbox id for test purposes)

Autocomplete:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var products= JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($products_list) ?>' );
 var t = 0;
 var r = '<?php echo json_encode($number_of_rows_tuote) ?>';
 var availableProducts = [];
 var cellPlace = [];

 while(t < r){
 availableProducts.push(products[t]['prsku']+":"+products[t]['prname']);
 cellPlace.push(t);
  t++;
  }

  $( "#product2" ).autocomplete({
source: availableProducts
});

});
```

Dynamic create content

```
function addElement()
{

var contentID = document.getElementById('more');
var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
newTBDiv.innerHTML ="<br><div class='product'><TABLE><tr>";

newTBDiv.innerHTML += "<td><input type='text' placeholder = 'product_code' name='sku_" + intTextBox + "' id='sku_" + intTextBox + "'/></td><td><input type='text' id='product2' name='product2'></td>;

contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
}


<body onload="addElement();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Call function to bind autocomplete as shown below and remove `onload` from body.

```
<body>
```

**NOTE** - you have missed `"` at the end of dynamic element string i.e. after `</td>`, please correct it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var products= JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($products_list) ?>' );
 var t = 0;
 var r = '<?php echo json_encode($number_of_rows_tuote) ?>';
 var availableProducts = [];
 var cellPlace = [];

 while(t < r){
 availableProducts.push(products[t]['prsku']+":"+products[t]['prname']);
 cellPlace.push(t);
  t++;
  }

  $('body').load(function(){
      var contentID = document.getElementById('more');
        var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
        newTBDiv.innerHTML ="<br><div class='product'><TABLE><tr>";

        newTBDiv.innerHTML += "<td><input type='text' placeholder = 'product_code' name='sku_" + intTextBox + "' id='sku_" + intTextBox + "'/></td><td><input type='text' id='Product2' name='product2'></td>";
        contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
       //bind autocomplete
       $( "#Product2").autocomplete({
        source: availableProducts
       });
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about missin ". Thew bindAutocomplete does not seem to work. First I get thet error that available products is not defined, when moving the definition part to same function I get TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Comment: Sorry, still does not work. Could it be caused by conflict in including scripts? Another site had a person with similar problem and that was his solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your autocomplete function after the addElement function .
OR
simply add 
    $( "#product2" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableProducts
    });
these lines at the last of your addElement function like this

```
            function addElement()
            {

            var contentID = document.getElementById('more');
            var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
            newTBDiv.innerHTML ="<br><div class='product'><TABLE><tr>";

            newTBDiv.innerHTML += "<td><input type='text' placeholder = 'product_code' name='sku_" + intTextBox + "' id='sku_" + intTextBox + "'/></td><td><input type='text' id='product2' name='product2'></td>;

            contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
            $( "#product2" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableProducts
            });

            }
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. First I get thet error that available products is not defined, when moving the definition part to same function I get TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function